# VirtualBox for PHP app on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, vagrant, virtualbox, puphpet

I'm trying to set up a virtual environment using Vagrant. I want to match my production PHP environment on Heroku.

I'm about to try to set up my own using [puphpet](https://puphpet.com/) but I'm worried that I'll be "re-inventing the wheel" since Heroku has become such a popular hosting platform... I found several Heroku VirtualBoxes for *Ruby* development, but none of these have PHP installed:

- https://atlas.hashicorp.com/lazygray/boxes/heroku-cedar-14
- http://icebergist.com/posts/quick-virtualboxvagrant-setup-with-heroku-like-box/

  1. Is there an equivalent for PHP?
  2. If not, does it make sense for me to hack those to add PHP? [Tips welcome]
  3. Or am I better off rolling my own from scratch with Puphpet? [Tips welcome]

Answer (score 0):

> Or am I better off rolling my own from scratch with Puphpet? [Tips welcome]

By definition, using PuPHPet isn't starting from scratch. You select boxes, click a few buttons, type `$ vagrant up` and you have an environment.

Using it will also be much faster than #2.